# GridView não é atualizada (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, asynctask, adapter

estou criando um app que ao iniciar ele executa uma tarefa assíncrona que faz uma consulta a uma api, ao pegar o resultado ela vai inserindo no adapter. Já tentei de vários jeitos, mas só aparece as imagens quando seleciono no menu sort by e é executado a tarefa novamente.

Sempre que executo aparece  no logcat: E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Gostaria que assim que executa-se as imagens fossem carregadas no GridView.

Segue meu código:

```
public class BrowserMoviesActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private MovieAdapter m_MovieAdapter;
private List<Movie> m_Movies;
private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog;
private String m_SortType = Constants.SORT_POPULAR_PARAM;
private MenuItem m_MenuItemSortPopular;
private MenuItem m_MenuItemSortRating;

public BrowserMoviesActivityFragment() { setHasOptionsMenu(true); }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browser_movies, container, false);

    m_Movies = new ArrayList<>();
    m_MovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), m_Movies);

    GridView gridViewMovie = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewMovie);
    gridViewMovie.setAdapter(m_MovieAdapter);

    gridViewMovie.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailMovieActivity.class).putExtra("MOVIE", m_Movies.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    if(isOnline()) {
        new FetchMoviesTask().execute(m_SortType);
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_browser_movies, menu);

    m_MenuItemSortPopular = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort_popular);
    m_MenuItemSortRating = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort_rating);

    if(m_SortType.contentEquals(Constants.SORT_POPULAR_PARAM)) {
        if(!m_MenuItemSortPopular.isChecked()) {
            m_MenuItemSortPopular.setChecked(true);
        }
    } else if(m_SortType.contentEquals(Constants.SORT_RATE_PARAM)) {
        if(!m_MenuItemSortRating.isChecked()) {
            m_MenuItemSortRating.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_sort_popular:
            if(isOnline()) {
                changeSort(Constants.SORT_POPULAR_PARAM);
                if(!m_MenuItemSortPopular.isChecked()) {
                    m_MenuItemSortPopular.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.action_sort_rating:
            if (isOnline()) {
                changeSort(Constants.SORT_RATE_PARAM);
                if(!m_MenuItemSortRating.isChecked()) {
                    m_MenuItemSortRating.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}

private void changeSort(String sort) {
    m_SortType = sort;
    if(isOnline()) {
        new FetchMoviesTask().execute(m_SortType);
    }
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnected() || !networkInfo.isAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.message_offline), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Movie>> {

    IMovieService m_MovieService;
    List<Movie> movieList = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Loading...", "Searching movies...");
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String sort = params[0];
        m_MovieService = MovieClient.createService(IMovieService.class);

        Call<ResponseAPI<Movie>> moviesCall = m_MovieService.getMovies(sort);
        try {
            Response<ResponseAPI<Movie>> response = moviesCall.execute();
            movieList = response.body().getResults();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.message_offline), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return movieList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result) {
        m_MovieAdapter.clear();
        if(result != null) {
            for (Movie movie : result) {
                m_MovieAdapter.add(movie);
            }
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Quando você modificar os dados do adapter tente chamar m_MoviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Opa, eu já fiz isso antes, porém continua do mesmo jeito.

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está modificando os dados do adapter, mas não está "avisando" a ele. Para isso basta chamar o método `m_MoviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` após adicionar ou remover um `movie`

Modifique o método `onPostExecute()` do seu `FetchMoviesTask` para :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result) {
        m_MovieAdapter.clear();
        if(result != null) {
            for (Movie movie : result) {
                m_MovieAdapter.add(movie);
            }

         m_MoviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Opa, eu já fiz isso, porém continua do mesmo jeito.